# google sheet : is it possible to import custom function from other spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, worksheet-function

I have 2 spreadsheet : A and B. I created my custom function **function_A()** in spreadsheet A :

```
function function_A() {
   return("test")
}
```

it works and i want to use it in spreadsheet B. How can i import my custom function to B ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your actual goal, for example, as a simple method, how about copying the script of Google Spreadsheet A to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet B?

Comment: The problem if i want to use it in many spreadsheet : B, C, D, ... ZZ then i have to make so many copy, it’s not efficient as it’s hard to debug or to update the function. I have to go one by one. Using 1 single master function as lib will be easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now I noticed that your question has been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

As an alternate solution to what [@Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) proposed you can use Apps Script Libraries. In this way you can import external Apps Script code to your project to improve readability and enable code extensibility.

### Example

Your Spreadsheet_A bound Apps Script project looks like this:

```js
function function_A() {
  return "output_A";
}
```

Now, in order to use this code on you *"Spreadsheet_B"* you will need to import it using the *"Spreadsheet_A"* Apps Script project *"Script ID"*.

You can find this in the Apps Script *"Project Settings"*.

Once you have copied, switch to the *"Spreadsheet_B"* bound Apps Script project and import the *"Spreadsheet_A"* library using its *"Script ID"*. Go to `Resources>Libraries` and paste the *"Script ID"* in the *"Add a Library"* input field. Lastly, click *"Add"*.

Note that the library will now have an Identifier assigned. You can edit it according to your needs. In this example I will use the letter "A".

Now you can simply create a new `function_B()` in your *"Spreadsheet_B"* bound Apps Script project that internally uses the `function_A()` from the Apps Script library:

```js
/*
* @customfunction
*/
function function_B() {
  return A.function_A() + " from function_B";
}
```

### References

[Apps Script Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Perfecto, It works great. But i have a question, if possible that rather than connecting it using script ID , is there any method to make my function as 'global' to all my spreadsheet ? Some other app i used, they have API to create custom function and load it as 'global' function so it will immediatelly accessible to all my project.

Comment: In this case, I would suggest using an [Editor Add-On](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/building-editor-addons). You can define a function in the add-on install it and use it in every Spreadsheet you will use with your account. You will have to start the add-on on new Spreadsheet though.